# Math function in c programmin

Tags: logic

I'm making a function which is supposed to resolve the following problem:
Workers are given points by judges based on their production time. If their time is 20min or more they get 120 points, and for every 0.5 min in a decrease of production time, they get extra 1,4 points. I came up with this:

```
-2.8X + 176 = Y
```

Where Y is a number of points and X is production time, this works if production time is exactly 19.5 or 19 minutes ... but not for 19.2 for example, also if I get a result less then 120 I can use if statement to change it to 120 but I'm not sure how to solve not exactly 0.5 change in minutes

Comment: What is your **question**? Are you sure it is a question about mathematics?

Comment: Its about making math function to solve a problem i guess it is

Comment: You have not told **what your question is**. You have described a situation, but so far failed to **ask** something, mathematical or otherwise, about the situation you describe.

Comment: I presented the problem, question is if its possible to make function which can calculate points based on minutes

Comment: i wrote in my post function i came up with

Answer (score 1):

This is more a programming question, nonetheless, the answer is simple. Once you've established that the time is less than 20 minutes (with some flow control) you can say:
$$Y = 120 + 1.4 *((int)(10*(20 - x))/5) $$
Adding (int) before a float number in $C$ is basically a floor operation which turns any real number into a whole number, by removing everything past the decimal point.

Edit: Because it seems that OP doesn't understand how to use this function or isn't convinced it works for floating types I suggest testing what this code prints to standard output.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 19.2;
    float Y = 120 + 1.4 *((int)(10*(20 - x))/5);
    printf("%f",Y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: everything is given in float type, but tnx anyway

Comment: that doesn't matter as you do the (int) cast

Comment: The point is that the cast to int is what you need to solve the problem you were having with 19.2 for example.

Comment: perhaps it's possible to just use 1.4*(2*(20-x)) and round number in a bracket to lower integer value?

Comment: Does the take that if $x > 20$ the get the full $120$ anyway?  Do you need a max(20-x, 0)?  Or am I not reading this right?

Comment: For your first question, no, that's not possible, try it with paper and pen. I don't understand the second question. For the third question, no, you don't need any $max$ because you'll use an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume there is a floor function and max/min function:

Let's think this out slowly.

Let $x = $ production time.

Let $y = 20 - x$ be the amount of time they saved. But that will be negative if they took longer.

Let $y = max(20-x, 0)$

Let $unit = 2y$ is the number of half minutes.  But this isn't rounded down.

Let $unit = \lfloor 2y\rfloor$ is the number of half minutes.

Then $pay = 120 + 1.4*unit$.

so....

$pay = 120 + 1.4\lfloor 2(max(20 - x,0))\rfloor$